# Devexpress LookUpEdit - serach second column by value meber

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I want to know it is posible to filters **LookUpEdit ** dropdown list by the column that corresponds to the ValueMember value.

```
        LookUpEdit.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        LookUpEdit.ValueMember = ds.Tables(0).Columns("VALUE").Caption.ToString
        LookUpEdit.DisplayMember = ds.Tables(0).Columns("DISPLAYtext").Caption.ToString
        LookUpEdit.View.FocusedRowHandle = DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.AutoFilterRowHandle
        LookUpEdit.AllowFocused = True
        LookUpEdit.CloseUpKey = New KeyShortcut(Keys.Add)
        LookUpEdit.NullText = ""
```

**I using devexpress 14.2.3. and vb.net**

Answer (score 0):

You can display in your LookUpEdit additionally "VALUE" column, that will allow you to search.
Or you can overwrite search mechanism.

EDIT:
Eases way, i think, is display value column, like this:

```
<dxg:LookUpEdit AutoPopulateColumns="False" ValueMember="VALUE" DisplayMember="DISPLAYtext">
<dxg:LookUpEdit.StyleSettings>
<dxg:SearchLookUpEditStyleSettings/>
</dxg:LookUpEdit.StyleSettings>
<dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
<ControlTemplate>
<dxg:GridControl AutoGenerateColumns="None" Name="PART_GridControl">
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Value"/>
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="DISPLAYtext"/>
</dxg:GridControl.Columns>
<dxg:GridControl.View>
<dxg:TableView NavigationStyle="Row" ShowGroupPanel="False" ShowTotalSummary="False" AutoWidth="True"/>
</dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
</ControlTemplate>
</dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
</dxg:LookUpEdit>
```

So or you can override LookUpEdit. Sorry, i dont know how it correct write on VB, but idea similar:

```
public class MyLookUpEdit : LookUpEdit
{
    public MyLookUpEdit()
    {
        currentItems = new List<TestDataItem>();
    }

    private List<TestDataItem> currentItems;

    protected override void OnDisplayTextChanged(string displayText)
    {
        base.OnDisplayTextChanged(displayText);
        this.currentItems.Clear();
        var filter = (displayText).ToLower();
        foreach (var item in ((IEnumerable<TestDataItem>) this.ItemsSource).Where(x => this.Filter(x, filter)))
        {
            this.currentItems.Add(item);
        }
        currentItems.Sort(new Comparison<TestDataItem>((el1, el2) =>
        {
            int elt1 = CompareStrings(el1.Value, filter);
            int elt2 = CompareStrings(el2.Value, filter);
            return elt2 - elt1;
        }));
        if (GetGridControl() != null)
        {
            GetGridControl().ItemsSource = currentItems;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (GetGridControl().RefreshData));
        }
    }

    private bool Filter(TestDataItem item, string filter)
    {
        if (filter.Length < 2) return false;
        int res = CompareStrings(item.Value, filter);
        if (res > 1) return true;
        /**/
        return false;
    }

    public int CompareStrings(string str1, string str2)
    {
        int res = 0;
        if (str1 == str2) return 2;
        /**/
        return res == 0 ? 1 : res;
    }
}
```

or override OnAutoSearchTextChanged in LookUpEdit